# How to get requesting page controller name in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have controller "**Account**", in which there is an action "**UploadImage**".  This action can called from another actions.

I'm calling this action from another action "**AddProduct**" from "**Product**" Controller using Jquery.

Now what I want, Whenever my **UploadImage** action is invoked, I want to know the requesting controller or action name in **UploadImage**.

Like If I'm calling that action from **AddProduct** then, 
in UploadImage, ActionName name should be **AddProduct**.

I have done this

```
string actionName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
string controllerName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

But This is always giving me

actionName : UploadImage

controllerName : Account

**Solution 1** : I have option to pass the action name in ajax call but i don't want to do that. I want to get It In server side.

Comment: I'm guessing you want this to redirect back to the calling page? In which case you should pass the calling action/controller in as a `redirectUrl` parameter.

Comment: @Steve: No. actually I have perform some other task on the basis of requesting action name.

Comment: Are you using ajax calls to call this method from elsewhere ?

Comment: @AmitKumar How do you call the first action from second action? Do you mean Performing an ajax call to second action while you are in view of first action? or do you mean a redirection? or something else?

Comment: @MattMurdock: yes. I have option to pass the action name in ajax call but i don't want to do that. I want to get It In server side.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: yes, I'm using ajax call. and through ajax call I can call any action.

Comment: So you can pass @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] to the action as a parameter.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: this is the last option to pass the action name in ajax call . Is there any other way so that I can get requesting page Url or action name

Comment: Just for a trying sake, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830052/how-do-i-get-the-controller-and-action-names-from-the-referrer-uri

Comment: @MattMurdock: This is what I'm looking for.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @AmitKumar - Cool. Thanks.